# How to send websocket updates to any connected clients while running a while-True loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have a Python3 program that runs a "*while True*"-loop until stopped, which occasionally saves data to a MySQL database. I am creating an administrative website, separate from the Python program, where I will be able to observe this data.

I now want to be able to be notified, on the website, when changes have been made to the database. My thought was to set up a websocket connection, so that the Python program can send a message through the socket to all connected clients, i.e. all open browsers, if there has been any changes to the database table.

I have done something similar before, but in that case I had to wait for a websocket connection before the "*while True*"-loop would start. In the new scenario I want to be able to have multiple website clients at once, and let them connect at any time, as well as disconnect without interrupting the Python programs loop.

This is a simplified version of my previous code, which I now want to update to be able to run both with & without websocket clients.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

socket_server = websockets.serve(run, "127.0.0.1", 5055)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(socket_server)
console_log("Waiting for socket connection...")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

async def run(ws):
    while True:
        db_has_updated = do_stuff()
        if db_has_updated:
            await ws.send(data)
```

I just can't seem to be able to come up with the right search terms to find a solution, so I'm asking here instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, finally! Here is my solution with a websocket server running in a separate thread from the other logic. I'm probably changing some things to make it neater, but this does everything I need. Feel free to ask any questions.

Be aware that this blocks when messaging all the connected clients. That is the way I needed it to work, but you could always thread/subprocess the logic/data-gen part of the program if you want it to run completely asynchronously.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import websockets
import threading
import time
import random

def gen_data():
    print("Generating data...")
    time.sleep(3)
    data = random.randint(1, 10)
    
    return data

async def send(client, data):
    await client.send(data)

async def handler(client, path):
    # Register.
    print("Websocket Client Connected.", client)
    clients.append(client)
    while True:
        try:
            print("ping", client)
            pong_waiter = await client.ping()
            await pong_waiter
            print("pong", client)
            time.sleep(3)
        except Exception as e:
            clients.remove(client)
            print("Websocket Client Disconnected", client)
            break

clients = []
start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 5555)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
threading.Thread(target = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever).start()

print("Socket Server Running. Starting main loop.")

while True:
    data = str(gen_data())
    message_clients = clients.copy()
    for client in message_clients:
        print("Sending", data, "to", client)
        try:
            asyncio.run(send(client, data))
        except:
            # Clients might have disconnected during the messaging process,
            # just ignore that, they will have been removed already.
            pass
```